# Subset for SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql

I have the following code to write the rows with min and max timestamp into a new table:

```
sql_sort_and_delete = """
                CREATE TABLE tmp AS
                SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c2g
                WHERE time = (SELECT max(time) FROM c2g)
                UNION SELECT DISTINCT * FROM c2g
                WHERE time = (SELECT min(time) FROM c2g);;"""
```

It works fine however there are subsets for different cities in the c2g table and I would like to change the code so that I get the distinct min / max result for each city.
Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: please add the table structure, using http://sqlfiddle.com would be even nicer ;)

Comment: please add tag for software? sql-server / mysql / ... ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe over complicating things slightly or maybe a valid way of coding this with `CTE`:

[SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/059ff/4)

```
CREATE TABLE c2g 
    ( 
     CITY varchar(20), 
     TIME INT
    );

INSERT INTO c2g
(CITY, TIME)
VALUES
('A', 1),
('A', 2),
('B', 2),
('B', 2),
('B', 2),
('B', 2),
('C', 1),
('C', 2),
('C', 5),
('C', 20);
```

To get required records:

```
WITH CITY_cte(CITY, myMAX, myMIN)
AS
(
  SELECT
      CITY
      ,MAX(TIME) 
      ,MIN(TIME) 
  FROM c2g
  GROUP BY CITY
)
SELECT x.* 
FROM  
    c2g x
    INNER JOIN CITY_cte y
        ON x.CITY = y.CITY
WHERE 
  x.TIME = y.myMAX 
  OR
  x.TIME = y.myMIN
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the aggregate `MIN()/MAX()` per city, use a `GROUP BY city`.  To pull the remaining columns from `c2g`, you then need to `INNER JOIN` the main table against that subquery on the city and time value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2g.*
FROM
  c2g
  INNER JOIN (SELECT city, MAX(time) AS time FROM c2g GROUP BY city) maxtime
    ON c2g.city = maxtime.city AND c2g.time = maxtime.time
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT c2g.*
FROM
  c2g
  INNER JOIN (SELECT city, MIN(time) AS time FROM c2g GROUP BY city) mintime
    ON c2g.city = mintime.city AND c2g.time = mintime.time
```

I think this can be simplified and would actually work without the `UNION` by using an `OR` in the join's `ON` condition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2g.*
FROM
  c2g
  INNER JOIN (SELECT city, MAX(time) AS maxtime, MIN(time) AS mintime FROM c2g GROUP BY city) maxtime
    ON c2g.city = maxtime.city AND (c2g.time = maxtime.time OR c2g.time = maxtime.mintime)
```

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can also do this with windows functions, by doing something like:

```
select c.*
from (select cg.*,
             max(time) over (partition by city) as maxtime,
             min(time) over (partition by city) as mintime
      from c2g
     ) c
where time = maxtime or time = mintime
```

(This definitely doesn't work in mysql or Access, since they do not support windows functions.)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT City, MAX(Time)
FROM cg
GROUP BY City
UNION
SELECT City, MIN(Time)
FROM cg
GROUP BY City
```